# Поставить фильтры в tagmanager2

Tags: modx

Пытаюсь поставить фильтры в `tagmanager2` MODX,
но при сохранении ничего не сохраняется в журнале ошибок.

Нашел это:

```
/core/xpdo/om/xpdoobject.class.php : 1452) Error HY000 executing statement:
INSERT INTO `modx_tag_manager2_tags` (`category`, `tvid`, `tvname`, `tvcaption`, `tags`, `index`) VALUES (31, 4, 'price', 'Цена', '[{\"value\":\"670\",\"active\":true},{\"value\":\"23900\",\"active\":true}]', 0)
Array
(
[0] => HY000
[1] => 1366
[2] => Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xA6\xD0\xB5\xD0\xBD...' for column 'tvcaption' at row 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там кодировка в таблице не верная, если в конфиге modx utf8, то решение:
ALTER TABLE modx_tag_manager2_tags MODIFY tvcaption varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8;

Подробнее решение описал тут https://tech4fun.ru/2018/04/08/modx-tagmanager2-fail/